# Telos / Eos - adding additional R1 key to existing wallet

Tags: eos, eosio, telos, eosioswift

I want to add an R1 typed key to an existing Telos wallet which was created with a WIF typed key.

I tried via Code and via Web.
Eos Authority -> change permission -> active key -> pasting in the public key PUB_R1_6Dxxx... is leading to "invalid active key".

Adding a WIF key to an existing R1-Key wallet via code with `updateauth` doesn't cause any trouble and both keys are afterwards shown in the wallet. Adding an R1 the same way doesn't work.

Is it possible in generell to add an R1 key to an existing telos/eos wallet?